# Using expression and non-ASCII character in R ggplot axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, character-encoding, expression, cairo

I am trying to plot a chart using `ggplot`with superscript and non-ASCII characters. While expression with superscript works with simple characters as shown below:

*relative part of `ggplot` script*

```
      labs(
    y = "těžba, C [t]",
    x = "rok") +  
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6, accuracy = 1),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*4.2, name = expression("objem [m"^"3" * "]"),
                     breaks = seq(0,4e7,5e6), labels = function(b) { paste0(round(b/1000000, 0), " M")}))  +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc4Q1.png)

I get error when trying to use expression with this characters: `ěž` while on the lext y axis without expression() there is no problem.

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6, accuracy = 1),
                   sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*4.2, name = expression("těžba, objem [m"^"3" * "]"),
                   breaks = seq(0,4e7,5e6), labels = function(b) { paste0(round(b/1000000, 0), " M")}))
```

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
> Metric information not available for this family/device

I couldn't find no workaround. Any help aprreciated.

---

**EDIT**

The problem occurs when trying to export image using `png` or `cairo-png` devices with different error messages. The default device without antialias is working.

```
- Session info -----------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Czech_Czechia.1250          
 ctype    Czech_Czechia.1250          
 tz       Europe/Prague               
 date     2021-01-06
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. maybe try update R, all packages, and start a new session.

Comment: You having edited the question - does it mean it's still causing a problem? Not everyone will have their ggplot questions set on "most recently active on top" setting. As per my comment below, when I used your exact code for saving (for convenience: `ggsave("plot.png",dpi=150, type = "cairo-png", antialias = "subpixel")`, I got a png file with perfectly rendered symbols. As suggested, this may be a problem of your language setting (`Czech_Czechia.1250` instead of `en_GB.UTF-8`), or maybe you need to update your renderer (in this case Cairo)?

Comment: @tjebo Yes, it is still causing an error. But the problem looks more related to the device renderer than ggplot. Should I change the question title?

Comment: Not sure if it is useful, I think the title is ok. have you tried re-installing cairo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment, here a reproducible example - showing how I tried to reproduce it - which I cannot.

It may be that your packages are not up to date or simply that you need to restart a new session :)

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
labs( y = expression("těžba, objem [m"^"3" * "]"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#>  os       macOS Catalina 10.15.7      
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_GB.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/London               
#>  date     2021-01-06                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        

#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.2   2020-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
```

Comment: I have all the latest versions. And restarting R was just enough, my bad. Sorry. Anyway it helped me a lot.

Comment: Maybe you could add your comment on restarting to your answer and I can accept it...

Comment: Can you try `ggsave("plot.png",dpi=150, type = "cairo-png", antialias = "subpixel")` ? Now I get the same error upon exporting image. Definitely it's error connected to rastering device.

Comment: @AlbinePro With ggsave and ASCII characters - I think this may have been asked before. Let me have a quick search. If not, may be worth to ask a follow up question - will let you know.

Comment: @AlbinePro I cannot reproduce this on my Mac (see more details in the sessionInfo) - my png file looks fine. I used your exact code for saving to png

Comment: with fonts etc I believe it can be of real relevance in which language you are writing. look my sessionInfo "language / collate / ctype"